# Ostrich eats a diamond and is chased by people

Tags: identify-this-movie

What's the name of the following movie? It's set in Africa. An ostrich eats a diamond and everyone chases him. The main character rides a three wheeled motorcycle, has an axe, and falls in love with a blonde. A UN troop (United States Army) also chases the diamond. There is a scene when he is in some store, pulls some rope and activates a cannon which shoots and scares monkeys which run away from some watermelons in a garden, I think.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like the South African comedy ['Kwagga Strikes Back'](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099961/combined) (AKA 'Oh Schucks...! Here Comes U.N.T.A.G.') from 1990. From an online recap (I highlighted the relevant bits):

> One day, a ragtag bunch of **UNTAG soldiers** set up camp near Kwagga’s home. They take pot-shots at Kwagga’s **three-wheeled bike** and accidentally destroy his shop. When the locals’ cattle go missing, Kwagga decides enough is enough. He starts playing outrageous pranks on the soldiers and also discovers a plot **involving an ostrich and a gigantic diamond**.

And here's a [Youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeFPg3chHpE) from the end of the movie where a chain is pulled and then a Rube Goldberg machine makes a cannon fire at a watermelon patch and scare some baboons. I can't believe I just typed that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell, but I believe you might be thinking of "[The Southern Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Southern_Star_%28film%29)", as that is about the only movie I can find with diamond eating ostriches.